# How to filter in & filter out by the column names in the same time in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the data frame with the part of columns named in a similar pattern.
(example: `first_susceptibility_test_penicillins_ampicillin_bli`, `first_susceptibility_test_penicillins_ampicillin_bli_s`).
Depending on the absence or existence of `"_s"` at the end of the column name, the variables will have different levels of factors (`"Tested/Not tested"` and `"Sensitive/Intermediate/Resistant"` respectively).

I have tried to use the code with `which` and `grepl`, but it does not work.

```
[which(grepl("first_susceptibility_test", names(df), ignore.case=FALSE)&
  !grepl("_s", names(df), ignore.case=FALSE)]
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: You should give more details. What doesn't work, do you get an error (then what is the error) or a wrong result (then, what result do you get) ?...

Comment: For the simple example given I think `df[, !grepl("_s", names(df), ignore.case=FALSE)]`  alone should work.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, your proposal will work, but there are other columns, which should not be included into this filter.

Comment: I have just used 
sens <-df[,which(grepl("first_susceptibility_test", names(df), ignore.case=FALSE)&
  !grepl("_s", names(df), ignore.case=FALSE))] and this code resulted in the data with 0 variables.

Comment: Then that should work e.g. try `iris[,which(grepl("Width", names(iris), ignore.case=FALSE) & !grepl("Petal", names(iris), ignore.case=FALSE))]` Are you sure you data is as you think?

Comment: Sorry . Silly me. Your problem is that `"_s"` is within `"first_susceptibility_test"` So you need to use regex that anchors `"_s"` at the end of the string.

Comment: Yep. I want to extract the columns containing "_s" from selected ones. Filter out from the filtered-

Comment: `!grepl("_s$", names(df), perl = TRUE)` $ is the end of string anchor.

Comment: Now have tried tidyverse, using
df %>% 
  filter(grepl("first_susceptibility_test", names(df), ignore.case = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(!grepl("_s", names(df), ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%          
  select(df) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  pull(patient_appendix_uc %>% 
  filter(grepl("first_susceptibility_test", names(patient_appendix_uc), ignore.case = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(!grepl("_s", names(patient_appendix_uc), ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%          
  select(patient_appendix_uc) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  pull(patient_appendix_uc))
Get an error message
"Error: Result must have length 190, not 232"

Comment: !grepl("_s$", names(df), perl = TRUE) seems to work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Stephen Henderson, I have changed variables numeric variables to factors and allocated factor levels in multiple columns (223 in total). Here is a code (for cases if someone will have a similar problem):

```
df[, grepl("susceptibility_test", names(df), perl = TRUE) & !grepl("_s$", names(df), perl = TRUE)] <- lapply(
  X = df[,grepl("susceptibility_test", names(df), perl = TRUE) & !grepl("_s$", names(df), perl = TRUE)],
  FUN = factor,
  levels = c(0, 1),
  labels = c("Not tested", "Tested"))

df[, grepl("susceptibility_test", names(df), perl = TRUE) & grepl("_s$", names(df), perl = TRUE)] <- lapply(
  X = df[, grepl("susceptibility_test", names(df), perl = TRUE) & grepl("_s$", names(df), perl = TRUE)],
  FUN = factor,
  levels = 0:2,
  labels = c("Sensitive", "Intermediate", "Resistant"))
```

Suppose that code might be more elegant, using `ifelse`, though.

Comment: could you format your code to fit into line, unfortunately with current formatting it's difficult to comprehend.